Why does the psutil CPU tracker not work in Google Cloud Run?
I'm currently working on a Tracker of CPU & RAM in python using psutil. I've made some tries locally and everything appears to work fine, but, when I deploy to Google Cloud Run, the tracker is not able to track the usage of CPU. (The RAM's tracker still working.)
Why isn't the CPU tracker working, and how can I fix it?
In case it helps, Imma drop the code of my tracker below
import psutil
import os
import time

def process_memory():
    """
Use the psutil library to access the memory statistics of the process using the ID obtained with os.getpid(). 
The returned  value corresponds to the Resident Set Size (RSS), 
which is the portion of the process's memory stored in RAM.

    Returns:
        int: RAM memory used by the process (in bytes).
    """

    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem_info = process.memory_info()
    return mem_info.rss

def Tracker(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        
        #####################################
        ## -- Before Function Execution -- ##
        #####################################

        # Measure Memory 
        mem_before = process_memory()

        # Measure CPU percentage 
        psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None)
        time.sleep(1)  

        ##############################
        ## -- Function Execution -- ##
        ##############################
        responses, final_tracker = func(*args, **kwargs)

        ###########################
        ## -- After Execution -- ##
        ###########################

        # Measure memory 
        mem_after = process_memory()
        consumed_memory = (mem_after - mem_before) / (1024 ** 2)  # Convert bytes to MB
        
        # Measure CPU percentage
        cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None)

        final_tracker = {
            "Memory Consumed (MB)": consumed_memory,
            "CPU Consumed (%)": cpu_usage
        }
 
        return responses, final_tracker
    return wrapper

I've tried to change the cloud run's configuration to set the CPU as always allocated, but that didn't work.

Cloud Run (and other Google compute services) use gVisor for virtualization of Linux syscalls. See Improved gVisor file system performance for GKE, Cloud Run, App Engine and Cloud Functions. I don't know but suspect that psutil's requirements for a Linux environment aren't satisfied by gVisor and thus it's not returning metrics such as CPU.

I'm unable to explain why but, after enabling Cloud Profiler (Cloud Run is not listed as supported but it works with Cloud Run), psutil reports CPU and memory but you'd need to confirm that these values are accurate.

Hi Dazz, just to confirm, are you telling me that after enabling Cloud Profiler psutil works?

Daz, I've just post another question being more precise on what I need, if you take a look I'd appreciated:  link

Yes, I deployed your code as-was to Cloud Run and CPU|memory reported zero as you showed. In an attempt to determine which syscalls were being made, I added Cloud Profiler to your code and redeployed but this time the CPU|memory reported non-zero values. I then removed Cloud Profiler and the values reverted to zero. I unable to explain why this is so.

That’s Interesting (and weird haha), would you mind to show me how did you do the implementation?

I'll add an answer

Procfile:
web: python3 main.py

requirements.txt:
google-cloud-profiler==4.1.0
psutil==6.0.0

main.py:
import googlecloudprofiler
import psutil
import os
import time

def process_memory():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem_info = process.memory_info()
    return mem_info.rss

def Tracker(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        
        #####################################
        ## -- Before Function Execution -- ##
        #####################################

        # Measure Memory 
        mem_before = process_memory()

        # Measure CPU percentage 
        psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None)
        time.sleep(1)  

        ##############################
        ## -- Function Execution -- ##
        ##############################
        func(*args, **kwargs)

        ###########################
        ## -- After Execution -- ##
        ###########################

        # Measure memory 
        mem_after = process_memory()
        consumed_memory = (mem_after - mem_before) / (1024 ** 2)  # Convert bytes to MB
        
        # Measure CPU percentage
        cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None)

        final_tracker = {
            "Memory Consumed (MB)": consumed_memory,
            "CPU Consumed (%)": cpu_usage
        }
 
        return final_tracker
    return wrapper

@Tracker
def add(x,y: int) -> int:
    return x + y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        googlecloudprofiler.start(
            service="psutil",
            service_version="0.0.1",
            verbose=3,
        )
    except (ValueError, NotImplementedError) as exc:
        print(exc)

    print(add(4,6))

When I run the code locally:
{'Memory Consumed (MB)': 0.0, 'CPU Consumed (%)': 12.3}

When I run the code locally under e.g. Podman:
{'Memory Consumed (MB)': 0.0, 'CPU Consumed (%)': 15.5}

When I run the code on Cloud Run without Cloud Profiler:
{'Memory Consumed (MB)': 0.0, 'CPU Consumed (%)': 0.0}

When I run the code on Cloud Run with Cloud Profiler:
{'Memory Consumed (MB)': 2.375, 'CPU Consumed (%)': 4.0}

